# Recording and playing sounds in Javascript using MediaSourceExtensions

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to record and play audio in html using MediaSourceExtensions and MediaRecorder.

here is my code:

```
async function recordAudio()
{
    let mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices;
    let MediaStream = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true});
    let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(MediaStream);
    let audio = document.querySelector('audio');
    let chunks = [];
    mediaRecorder.start(400);
    var mediaSource = new MediaSource();
    audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer("audio/mp4; codecs="mp4a.40.2"");
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (e) => 
    {
        sourceBuffer.appendSourceBuffer(e.data);
    };
}
```

here are the errors I'm getting(on Firefox):

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable (line 11).
```

what I'm going for is for the voice to be played almost immediately/400ms after the input but I have no idea how to fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the stream directly to the audio element without having it going through the `MediaRecorder` instance. You can do this by assigning the `MediaStream` instance to the [`srcObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject) of the `<audio>` element.

```js
audio.srcObject = MediaStream;
```

If you want to maniuplate the audio and create a controlled delay, then you could use the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) and manipulate the audio passing through.

In the example below the stream is passed through a [`DelayNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DelayNode) which can offset the playing time by a given value in seconds.

```js
const audioContext = new AudioContext();

const mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(MediaStream);
const delay = audioContext.createDelay();
const streamDestination = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

delay.delayTime.value = 0.4; // Set delay to 400ms.

mediaStreamSource.connect(delay); // Pass the stream through the delay.
delay.connect(streamDestination); // Pass the delay into a new, modified stream.
```

Use the Web Audio API stream and set it to the `<audio>` element..

```js
audio.srcObject = streamDestination.stream;
```

..or pass the audio signal directly to the speakers.

```js
delay.connect(audioContext.destination);
```